# How to calculate total in javascript to display in datatable column using backend data in Vue.js 2.6, Vue CLI 4, Vuetify 2.2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-cli-4

I'm using Vuetify's current [CRUD Datatable UI Component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) (compatible with Vue.js2) and I'm trying to calculate the subtotal of a product multiplying the product's quantity with its price. Previously I was testing it with static data in javascript, but now I connected the backend to retrieve actual data from the database. This is how I was doing it with static data:

**HTML:**

```
<template>
    <v-layout align-start>
        <v-flex>
            <v-container grid-list-sm class="pa-4 white">
                <v-layout row wrap>
                    <v-flex xs12 sm12 md12 lg12 xl12>
                    <v-data-table :headers="headerDetails" :items="details" hide-actions class="elevation-1">
                        <template v-slot:no-data>
                            <h3>There are no current products added on details.</h3>
                        </template>
                    </v-data-table>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</template>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        data(){
            return{

                headerDetails: [
                    { text: 'Product', value: 'product', sortable: false },
                    { text: 'Quantity', value: 'quantity', sortable: false },
                    { text: 'Price', value: 'price', sortable: false },
                    { text: 'Subtotal', value: 'subtotal', sortable: false },
                ],
                details:[
                    {product:'Product 1', quantity:'5', price:'10' },
                    {product:'Product 2', quantity:'5', price:'20' },
                    {product:'Product 3', quantity:'20', price:'15' },
                    {product:'Product 4', quantity:'10', price:'25' }
                ].map(detail => ({...detail, subtotal: detail.quantity*detail.price}) ),
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Adding an Array.map `.map(detail => ({...detail, subtotal: detail.quantity*detail.price}) ),` did the trick to calculate the total for each product, but only when displaying the static data as you can see in the following example:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|       Product       |     Quantity     |        Price        |     Subtotal     |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|      Product 1      |         5        |         10          |        50        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|      Product 2      |         5        |         20          |       100        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|      Product 3      |        20        |         15          |       300        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|      Product 4      |        10        |         25          |       250        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

Now that I've connected the backend, I had to erase the static data since it's not useful anymore, so I've changed the code a bit. Here is how it looks now:

**UPDATED HTML:**

```
<template>
    <v-layout align-start>
        <v-flex>
            <v-container grid-list-sm class="pa-4 white">
                <v-layout row wrap>
                    <v-flex xs12 sm8 md8 lg8 xl8>
                        <v-text-field @keyup.enter="searchBarcode()" v-model="code" label="Barcode">
                        </v-text-field>
                    </v-flex>
                    <v-flex xs12 sm12 md12 lg12 xl12>
                        <v-data-table :headers="headerDetails" :items="details" hide-default-footer class="elevation-1">
                            <template v-slot:no-data>
                                <h3>There are no current products added on details.</h3>
                            </template>
                        </v-data-table>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-container>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</template>
```

**UPDATED JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                headerDetails: [
                    { text: 'Product', value: 'product', sortable: false },
                    { text: 'Quantity', value: 'quantity', sortable: false },
                    { text: 'Price', value: 'price', sortable: false },
                    { text: 'Subtotal', value: 'subtotal', sortable: false },
                ],
                details:[].map(detail => ({...detail, subtotal: detail.quantity*detail.price}) ),
                code: '',
            }
        }, 
        methods: {
            searchBarcode(){
                let me=this;
                axios.get("api/Products/SearchProductBarcode/" + this.code).then(function(response){
                    me.addDetail(response.data);
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }); 
            }
            addDetail(data = []){
            this.details.push(
                {idproduct: data['idproduct'],
                product: data['name'],
                quantity: 10,
                price: 150}
            );
        },
        }
    }
</script>
```

What I'm attempting is to input the existing barcode in the text field and call the `searchBarcode()` which is triggered with a `keyup.enter` event. If the barcode exists in the database, it retrieves its data (Product Name, Quantity, Price) and adds it to the datatable as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

As you can see, the data is displayed as it should, except the subtotal. How can I calculate the total by multiplying the product's price with its quantity if there's nothing inside the `details:[]` array unless it's filled after triggering the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties to the rescue

```
<template>
  <v-layout align-start>
    <v-flex>
      <v-container grid-list-sm class="pa-4 white">
        <v-layout row wrap>
          <v-flex xs12 sm8 md8 lg8 xl8>
            <v-text-field
              v-model="code"
              label="Barcode"
              @keyup.enter="searchBarcode()"
            >
            </v-text-field>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs12 sm12 md12 lg12 xl12>
            <v-data-table
              :headers="headerDetails"
              :items="detailsWithSubTotal"
              hide-default-footer
              class="elevation-1"
            >
              <template v-slot:no-data>
                <h3>There are no current products added on details.</h3>
              </template>
            </v-data-table>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      headerDetails: [
        { text: 'Product', value: 'product', sortable: false },
        { text: 'Quantity', value: 'quantity', sortable: false },
        { text: 'Price', value: 'price', sortable: false },
        { text: 'Subtotal', value: 'subtotal', sortable: false }
      ],
      details: [],
      code: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    detailsWithSubTotal() {
      // Each new added detail, updates the detailsWithSubTotal
      // computed property, so you have the subtotal calc in
      // each detail
      return this.details.map((detail) => ({
        ...detail,
        subtotal: detail.quantity * detail.price
      }))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    searchBarcode() {
      axios
        .get('api/Products/SearchProductBarcode/' + this.code)
        .then(function(response) {
          this.addDetail(response.data)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
    addDetail(data = []) {
      this.details.push({
        idproduct: data['idproduct'],
        product: data['name'],
        quantity: 10,
        price: 150
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I tried using a computing property at one point but wasn't doing it correctly. Thank you for your solution!